# JIRA: Migrating custom field content manually

Tags: jira

In *Migrating custom field content manually* [JIRA docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Changing+Custom+Field+Types) state:

*Using a bulk edit operation, populate the new field with the value of the old field for all the issues found. (...)*

How do I populate the new field **with the value of the old field**? I know how to set a value of a field to a value, but after looking at it for a while I still don't know how to 'copy the values'.

Is this possible to copy values between fields using the bulk copy functionality?

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/42730/a-way-to-bulk-copy-custom-field-values-from-one-custom-field-to-another) article help any?

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom field of type X and want it to be type Y. Or some such case.

Rename the old field to "deprecated"
Create the new field
For each value in the old field run a query to select just the issues with that value:
  Run a bulk update on those issues to set the value in the new field.
Delete the old field

This is pretty tedious I know. The other approach is to use the REST API to retrieve each issue one at a time, decide what the value in the new field should be, update the issue. This approach can change 2 or 3 issues/second usually and is good if you have thousands of issues to change.